# Where did the ability to edit a plugin go?

Tags: plugin-development

I tried searching and going crazy looking for this, where did the ability to edit a plugin go in WordPress? I am using WordPress 4.7.2, logged in as an administrator and I can't find where to edit a plugin!

Previously I could go to Plugins and click Edit next to the plugin I wanted to change OR I could select Plugins and open Editor. Neither option is there for me anymore?

I used this occasionally when on the road and not in front of an FTP client to make small tweaks.

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Is this a multisite installation?  If so, then the editor is in My Sites > Network Admin > (Plugins | Themes) > Editor.  If not, then the only reason I can think of is that something (plugin or theme) has hooked into the  `user_has_cap` filter and removed the `edit_plugin` cap for the administrator account.

Comment: @Paul'SparrowHawk'Biron I am using the default theme on single site

Comment: then try deactivating plugins, on at a time, and see if the editor comes back.  When/if it does, you'll know which plugin has removed the cap.  If that doesn't identify the problem, then I'm at a loss.

Comment: Thank you @Paul'SparrowHawk'Biron that was it! The plugin causing this issue was: iThemes Security (coincidently, I have had other issues where the plugin took up 60gb of repetitive backups recently even though it was set NOT to). Do you want to submit as an answer and I will mark as the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect some plugin is hooking into the `user_has_cap` filter and removing the `edit_plugin` cap for the administrator account.

To find out if this is the case, try deactivating plugins, one at a time, and see if the editor comes back. When/if it does, you'll know which plugin has removed the cap.

**Edit:**

What you do once you find the plugin in question is a different matter.  If the plugin is *vital* to the functioning of your site, then see if it has a setting where you can tell it not to remove the `edit_{plugin,theme}` capability.

If it doesn't, then do **NOT** edit the source of the plugin to fix the problem (because your edit will get lost when/if that plugin's author updates it).  Instead, you can simply hook into `user_has_cap` yourself (in a plugin or theme you control) and add the cap back in.  If you do this, make sure you are hooking in with a *higher* priority than the plugin in question is using, e.g., `add_filter ('user_has_cap', 'your_func', 99999, 4) ;`.  See [user_has_cap](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_has_cap/) and [add_filter()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/) for more info on how to do this.